# flowplayer with videojs module and video-js

Tags: media, files

I'm not sure how to integrate [videojs](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module with [video-js](http://videojs.com/) libraries because at the moment I am using the code for *video-js* to open the *swf player* in my drupal page which works fine. However I can't get it to play *FLV type video* and that is because apparently I need *flowplayer* as fallback from *html5*.

My question is where should I place the *flowplayer* folder in conjunction with the rest? Should it go in `sites/all/libraries` and then I create a content type with field to use [videojs](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module?

Why do I even need [videojs](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module if you can just place [video-js](http://videojs.com/) javascript code and html code in body of node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the project page says

[image]

If you are using latest [videojs](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module i.e `7.x-2.3` with 3.x [video.js](http://videojs.com/) version it comes with *Flash* fallback. [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) library will handle the flash fallback option. You don't need to install *swf tools* or *flowplayer API*. You don't need to place *flowplayer* folder inside *libraries* folder.

If you would like to use [flow player API](https://www.drupal.org/project/flowplayer) you might need to use `7.x-1.x` version of [video.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module. As long as you follow installation instructions [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/videojs.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/README.md) you are good to go with `7.x-3.x` version of module. Make sure you use right library of [video.js](http://videojs.com/) version vs Module version as shown above and follow instructions in Readme file.

Comment: How do I then get it to play FLV ? The documentation says it should but many people have reported no luck with it. In fact I can't find anywhere to show it working with flv.

Comment: Found discussion regarding same here.. https://drupal.org/node/2079567

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question. If as you say video.js handles fallback then why would I need that to play flv? I just can't get the code right.

Comment: Just got it to work by getting code correct following my own logic but your answer is drupal related and is correct.